# Which is the sacred number in Hinduism?

Tags: numbers

Because of my curiosity I want to know if there are any most sacred number in Hinduism ?

Does Hinduism have more than one sacred number ?

What is logic behind those sacred number, does any old books providing detail explanation for it?

Comment: Probably the most sacred number in Hinduism is "one". The one Brahman.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, Do you have any reference for it.

Comment: Hi. Yes, the  vedas indirectly  and upanishds  directly are advocating  one Brahman.

Comment: this would lead opinion based answers..there r many like 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 100, 108, 1000, 1008....my opinion is 3 bcz it represents Trimurti and Triguna...Triguna is like RGB, u can make any colour from diff ratio of RGB, similarly every creation is made from diff ratio of Triguna(Satva, Rajas, Tamas)..

Comment: But still can we decide one most sacred number if possible from any solid reference using vedas or any other?

Comment: Sacred no. 18 is indication of victory, mahabharatha is 18, bhagavad gita is 18 chapter. sirmad bhavadam is 18000 verses.. there is secert regarding 18 as explained in the answer for the question

Comment: Anyone know significance of 18 in path to God?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind considering number 12 as special?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19791/what-is-the-reason-behind-considering-number-12-as-special)

Comment: Also, see [Significance of number 7 as per Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21112/2995).

Comment: Indian numerology is based on Katapayadi System. https://www.reddit.com/r/hinduism/comments/ctja4a/indian_numerology_katapayadi_system/

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35173/16530 1 Brahman,3 guna Prakriti,7 rishis/planets and 12 Adityas, 108 (12 horoscope houses x 9 planets) or (27 constellations x 4 padas)